# HCL three input odd parity

Tags: c

I have three inputs: a,b, and c. If my output is 1 then there are odd number of inputs with 1. Otherwise it is 0.

I have tried so far `(a && b && c) || (!a && !b && !c)`, `(a && b && c) || (!a && b && c)`, `(a && c) || (b&& !c)` and quite a few others. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean to say, "`a`, `b` and `c` are all either `0` or `1`: if an odd number of them are `1` then the output should be `1`, otherwise the output should be `0`"?

Comment: yes a,b,c all are either 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

How about `a ^ b ^ c`?

If only basic logic operators are allowed, you can use this

```
((a && b || !c) || (!a && !b || !c)) && (!a || !b || c) && (a || b || c)
```

as dbaupp commented, just equivalent transformation.

Comment: The trailing `& 1` is redundant.  Each input is only a zero or one, and the xor operator returns either a zero or one.  (+1 for correctness and brevity.)

Comment: oh forget to mention i am suppose to use only &&, || and ! operators.

Comment: @user1224765, `x ^ y` is the same as `(x || y) && !(x && y)` so use `x = a` and `y = b^c` and expand to compute `a ^ (b^c)`, and then use `x = b` and `y = c` to compute the `b ^ c` part.